# RequestMapping not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring Controller I have create 3 methods. Method 1 and Method 2 are working properly but Method 3 is giving me issue

Issue :

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCEample1/students/edit/2] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringServlet'
```

**Method 1 - Works Perfectly**
**http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCEample1/students/get**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllStudents(Model model){
    System.out.println("Fetching All Students");
    model.addAttribute("studentList", list);
    return "student";
}
```

**Method 2 - Works Perfectly**
**http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCEample1/students/1**

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    System.out.println("Fetching Student with Id " + id);
    model.addAttribute("currentStudent",list.get(id));
    return "student";
}
```

**Method 3 - Giving Error**
**http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCEample1/students/edit/1**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/${studentId}")
    public String editStudent(@PathVariable("studentId") int studentId, Model model){
        System.out.println("Edit Student with Index " + studentId);
        model.addAttribute("studentId",studentId);
        model.addAttribute("studentName",list.get(studentId));
        return "redirect:get";
    }
```

Comment: `/edit/${studentId}` you must remove `$`

Comment: @BogdanK : thanks for pointing it out. I think I have lost my mind. :-)

Comment: Instead of @RequestMapping(value="/edit/${studentId}") you should have this @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{studentId}")

Comment: If you're using spring-mvc 4.3.x, you could use @GetMapping(value="/get") instead of @RequestMapping(value="/get", method = RequestMethod.GET). Just a side-note, since it's already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove `$` from `@RequestMapping(value="/edit/${studentId}")`

For example, it must be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{studentId}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping value should be {studentId} instead of ${studentId}.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{studentId}")
public String editStudent(@PathVariable("studentId") int studentId, Model model){
    System.out.println("Edit Student with Index " + studentId);
    model.addAttribute("studentId",studentId);
    model.addAttribute("studentName",list.get(studentId));
    return "redirect:get";
}
```